# How to Fix the size of crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2008

I am developing vb.net application using VS2008. in that I am having bill module in that i have designed the report by fixing boundry with (hieght 8" & width 6"). ut problem is that when data item is greater than 5 items report gets extended and footer part gets printed on other page that should not be happen.
Is there any way to print some items on 1 page with complete bill details and remaining deta items on other bill with same format

please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Ya5,u can do it with section expert in paging option tab there is two way page after or visible records according u can set yur page margin in page setup option and page header and f00ter option(bill details) which u have to print on other page. .

Answer (score 0):

In Section Expert there is an option "Print at Bottom of Page", use that to keep the Page footer at bottom irrespective of the number of records present.